# Iterating over Object of Objects with filtering results

Tags: javascript, object

Hello Guys i have a problem, cause i have a task to fetch on API and then show results in specific order:

[image: The code shoud return this]

But what i've got is :

```
let toObject = (array) =>
array.reduce((obj,item) => {
    obj[item.name.toUpperCase()] = item
    return obj
}, {})

    fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/')
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then((data) => data.filter(x => x.borders.includes('POL')))
  .then(data => toObject(data))
  .then(data => Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }))).then(data => console.log(data))
```

But it isn't looking what it shoud look like. And i have no idea what to add so my code return results like the one from screenshot :(

Comment: What are you getting now?

Comment: Object keys are not guaranteed to be in any particular order.

Comment: Now i get the whole object and i need to filtrate it

Comment: What's that weird `Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }))` supposed to do?

Comment: Bergi converting to Array of Objects :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way by which you can achieve the same. It essentially uses [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to tranform the results to the required object.

```js
// Get the data using AJAX
$.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/')
  .then(data => {
    // Transform the results
    let transformed = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
      // In each iteration, assign the country's name as key to the accumulator
      acc[item.name.toUpperCase()] = {
        // Calculate neighbours using borders count
        hasMoreThanFourNeighbours: item.borders.length > 4 ? "YES" : "NO",
        // Area with suffix KM2
        area: item.area + " KM2",
        // Population
        population: item.population
      };
      
      // Return the accumulator for next iteration
      return acc;
    }, {});

    console.log(transformed);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Would be great, but it needs to be in pure js

Comment: @Thomas -- it is indeed pure js. jQuery was used just to fetch the data. Transformation is completely done in JS and doesn't depend on jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

try using map

```
fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/')
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then((data) => data.filter(x => x.borders.includes('POL')))
.then((data) => data.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.name.toUpperCase()] = {
        hasMoreThanFourNeighbors: item.borders.length > 4 ? 'YES' : 'NO',
        population: item.population,
        area: item.area + ' KM2'
    };
    return obj;
}, {}))
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: Matt this is almost correct, but i can work with that! Thank U! i cannot make +1 cause i need reputiation +15

Comment: or i cant cause i need to remove also name value but i cannot do it cause then i cannot make toUpperCase in my toObject

Comment: take a look now

Comment: Thx Matt!!Youre the Best!